# How can I make an object in my parent class but bless it into my child class in Perl?

Tags: perl, constructor, types, polymorphism

I have two classes: a base class, Foo::Base and a derived class, `Foo::Base::Sub`.  I want to have `Foo::Base::Sub` do some type and data checking on the constructor`s argument--a hash--before blessing it.  I've tried overriding `Foo::Base->new`'s constructor, doing the checks and then calling `Foo::Base->new` (since the code would be exactly the same):

```
package Foo::Base::Sub;

sub new {
    ...check argument's type and data...
    Foo::Base->new(%my_hash)
}
```

The problem is that by calling `Foo::Base`'s constructor, the hash will now be blessed as a Foo::Base object and not a Foo::Base::Sub object.  The obvious solution is simply to put the code from `Foo::Base::new` into `Foo::Base::Sub::new` but then I'm repeating code.  The other thing is that Foo::Base is not mine--thus I'd like to avoid having to modify it after the module has loaded or forking it unnecessarily.

It seems to me that this problem must have come up before and so there must be a canonical solution.  Moreover, it really touches on type coercion which is generally not an issue Perl.

So is there a simple modification or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: For type coercion, you may want to check out Moose if you haven't already. You can build a lot of "automatic" things into object and attribute construction.

Comment: I`ve actually used Moose before but I`m really trying to understand Perl`s guts a bit better.  In the past I`ve eschewed the OOP model in favour of imperative and pseudo-functional styles so this sort of thing has never come up.

Comment: We cover this situation in _Intermediate Perl_ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A standard Perl idiom is to use `SUPER` to call up the inheritance chain:

```
@Foo::Base::Sub::ISA = qw(Foo::Base);

sub new {
    my $package = shift;

    my $self = $package->SUPER::new();

    # Other subconstructor stuff here

    return $self;
}
```

As noted in the comments, `Foo::Base`'s constructor must use the two-argument form of `bless`:

```
sub new {
    my $package = shift;

    my $self = bless {}, $package;

    # Other superconstructor stuff here

    return $self;
}
```

When the superclass' constructor is called, `$package` will be the subclass.

Comment: Note that this only works if the superclass constructor uses the two-argument form of `bless` in order explicitly set the package name of the new object. (This is why you should always use `bless $self, $class`)

Comment: Another way of saying all that is that either the constructor of Foo::Base is broken or it's not.

Comment: Use the 'parent' pragma rather than manipulating @ISA directly.

Comment: Cool.  I've only used SUPER to guarantee the correct superclass's method is called.  Seeing your answer motivated me to take a closer look at perlobj and it all makes sense now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ether => everyone always says to `use parent` or `use base` but what is the reasoning behind that?  i can't imagine that the usage of @ISA is going to change and `our @ISA = qw/Foo::Base/` doesn't seem all that complicated and tells you exactly what is happening, and will explicitly complain about a base class not being required if it needs to be

Comment: @Eric Strom: multiple reasons; there are some funky order-of-compilation problems you can have if you set @ISA at run time instead of compile time (which BEGIN { our @ISA ... } would also address) and it's handy to enforce loading modules you subclass rather than (accidentally or on purpose) relying on some other module to have loaded them.  base also deals with subclassing a class that use fields.pm (a rare and I hope getting rarer beast)

Comment: @Eric Strom: no, it won't always complain: `perl -wle'{ package Quux; sub quux { print "hi" } } { package Foo::Bar::Baz; @ISA = qw/Foo::Bar Quux/ } Foo::Bar::Baz->quux'`  Here, the use of Foo::Bar::Baz automatically creates an empty Foo::Bar package, so you get no warning that `use Foo::Bar` was omitted.

Comment: One other caveat to be aware of: `$package->SUPER::new` actually calls the superclass of *the current package* (that is, as designated by the latest `package` declaration, or `main` if there was none), **not** of $package. This difference can usually be ignored as `$package` is either the same as or a child of \_\_PACKAGE\_\_, but if you're doing some funky polymorphism you may see results that can take a while to debug. :)

Comment: @ysth => good info, do you have any references that go into the details of the compilation order problems? i've mostly been avoiding base and parent since i find most of my sub-packages are small enough to inline, and the same file syntax is a little awkward.

Comment: @Eric Strom: no, I don't; it comes up on perlmonks from time to time, where people are doing recursive uses or have mainline code in modules trying to call methods that end up not being in the inheritance tree yet.  I'm having trouble coming up with a short example from memory.  I like parent's same file syntax.

Answer (score 7):

I'm used to split this to two parts, `new` and `init`.

```
package Foo::Base;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = bless {}, $class;
  return $self->init(@_);
}

sub init {
  my ($self, @params) = @_;
  # do something initialization and checks
  return $self;
}

package Foo::Sub;

use base 'Foo::Base';

sub init {
  my ($self, @params) = @_;
  # do something initialization and checks
  $self = $self->SUPER::init(@params);
  # do something other if you wish
  return $self;
}
```

Note that `'Foo::Sub'` doesn't implement `new` constructor.

Comment: Two-phased construction is less desirable if init() fails and you want the entire construction to fail as a result -- you'll end up with a partially-constructed object in an unknown and probably unusable state.

Comment: I like this answer from a pedagogical point of view but I'm loath to separate construction into two parts.  Especially when calling class->new(...) is so standard.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: When `init` fails then `new` fails because there is not any `eval` and `init` is called *inside* `new`. That's all.

Comment: When the init() fails, you just return nothing, which is the same thing that would happen if new() fails.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the various ways of invoking super.  The [SUPER](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SUPER) module may work although I havent tried it myself.

Comment: That's a good module, although its documentation is way out of date. Reading its source is quite educational, however.

Comment: Interesting.  I`m going to go over the source tonight.